# How do I check if array contains at least one empty value?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array ouput

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] =>  
)
```

How do I know the `[3] =>` is empty?

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value))
        echo "$key empty <br/>";
    else
        echo "$key not empty <br/>";
}
```

My out put showing all is not empty. What is correct way to check is empty?

Comment: Maybe because the third element is a white space `' '`, so it's not an empty string? If so, try change it in `if (trim($value) != '')`...

Comment: To avoid these issues, use var_dump() when printing out values. It will show the length and not hide those blank characters.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It works as expected, third one is **empty**

http://codepad.org/yBIVBHj0

Maybe try to trim its value, just in case that third value would be just a space.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $value = trim($value);
    if ($value === '')
        echo "$key is empty <br/>";
    else
        echo "$key is not empty <br/>";
}
```

Or to make it a function

```
function arrayHasEmptyValue(array $array) {    
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (trim($value) === '') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `$key` doesn't need to be declared in the second snippet because it is never used.

Answer (score 34):

Another solution:

```
$array = array('one', 'two', '');

if(count(array_filter($array)) == count($array)) {
    echo 'OK';
} else {
    echo 'ERROR';
}
```

http://codepad.org/zF9KkqKl

Also,

```
$containsEmpty = in_array("", $arr);
```

Should be a bit faster as it doesn't have to trace the entire array and doesn't have to create a new array.

Note that both solutions will consider `0`, `false`, `null` and empty array as empty values as well.

In case you also consider a value empty if it consists of space-like characters only, see [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367450/how-do-i-check-if-array-contains-at-least-one-empty-value#9367474)

Comment: If the task is merely to determine if any element has a zero-length value, then `!strlen()` should be used, then a `break` or `return` or `exit` (depending on context) to avoid doing unnecessary iterations.

Answer (score 10):

For a different task, when you need to tell if ALL array values are empty, you can use the following:

```
if (array_filter($array)) {
    echo 'OK';
} else {
    echo 'EMPTY ARRAY';
}
```

Comment: This looks like the correct answer to a different question.  If only readers bothered to compare the asked question with the functionality of the answer before voting. :(

Answer (score 3):

In case you also consider values empty if they contain only spaces, like below

```
$myArray = array('A', 'B', '  ');
```

here is the solution

```
if(in_array('', array_map('trim', $myArray), true)) {
   echo 'Found empty value in your array!';
}
```

Comment: This answer makes two passes over the input and does not have the ability to "short circuit" as a way to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_diff()` and `array_diff_key()`:

```
$array = array('one', 'two', '');
$emptyKeys = array_diff_key(array_diff($array,array()),$array);
```

`array_diff()` extracts all items which are not the same (therefore leaving out the blanks), `array_diff_key` gives back the differences to the original array.

Comment: This doesnt works  ..  php> print_r($array);
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => 
)

php> $emptyKeys = array_diff_key(array_diff($array,array()),$array);

php> print_r($emptyKeys);
Array
(
)

Comment: Even if this answer worked as expected in all scenarios, why would someone want to use two iterators when never more than one full iteration is necessary???

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution to check an array for empty key values and return the key.

```
$a = array('string', '', 5);

        echo array_search(null, $a);
        // Echos 1
```

To check if array contains an empty key value. Try this.

```
        $b = array('string','string','string','string','','string');

        if (in_array(null, $b)) {
            echo 'We found a empty key value in your array!';
        }
```

Comment: So you are demonstrating how both of these native functions perform loose comparisons?

Answer (score 0):

im using in my project like this for check this array

im posting form data like this `array('username' => 'john','surname' => 'sins');`

```
public function checkArrayKeyExist($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (!strlen($arr[$key])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: add some explanation

Comment: im added some explanation

Comment: `$arr[$key]` is more simply expressed as `$value`.  The `$key` declaration is not necessary since it is not returned.  `checkArrayKeyExist()` is a very poor/misleading choice for a method name.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $data=array(
        'title' => 'Test Name Four',
        'first_name' => '',
        'last_name' => 'M',
        'field_company' => 'ABC',
        'email' => '',
        'client_phone_number' => '',
        'address_line_1' => '',
        'address_line_2' => 'Address 3',
        'address_line_3' => '',
        'address_line_4' => '',
        'post_code' => '',
        );
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    foreach ($data as $key => $case ) { 
        echo "$key => ".is_multiArrayEmpty($case)."<br>"; 
    }
    function is_multiArrayEmpty($multiarray) { 
        if(is_array($multiarray) and !empty($multiarray)){ 
            $tmp = array_shift($multiarray); 
                if(!is_multiArrayEmpty($multiarray) or !is_multiArrayEmpty($tmp)){ 
                    return false; 
                } 
                return true; 
        } 
        if(empty($multiarray)){ 
            return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: What is the point of this unexplained recursive snippet dump?  Did you read the question and its sample data?