# If array item is empty

Tags: php, arrays

I've this array :

```
Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test2 [2] => test3 [3] => [4] => test4 )
```

I want to check if any array item is empty or not, as you can see, there's en empty item into my array : `[3] => [4] => test4`

So I wrote this condition :

```
           foreach ($array1 as $value) {

              if(!isset($value)) {
                echo "EMPTY";
              } else {
                echo "Not empty";
             }
          }
```

But it echo `Not empty` every time, there must have `empty` for one item

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/9367450/5470883 I think this answers your question

Answer (score 2):

You have to check like this:

```
foreach ($array1 as $value) {
    if ($value) {
        echo "Not empty";
    } else {
        echo "empty";
    }
}
```

It will display "empty" when there is an empty array or '' or zero value or null. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Php give you [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function for the task. empty() will determine whether a variable is empty.

```
 if(empty($value)) {
        echo "EMPTY";
    } else {
        echo "Not empty";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A good comparative study [here](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/)

In place of `isset` you may have to use `is_null`.

Answer (score 0):

For your query I can suggest following will be solution if values are string

```
$array1 = array(0 => 'test1', 1 => 'test2', 2 => 'test3', 3 => '',4 => 'test4');
foreach ($array1 as $value) {
              if($value =="") {
                echo "EMPTY";
              } else {
                echo "Not empty";
             }
          }
```

There is good [link](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) that will help you to understand the difference

Answer (score -1):

Please change your code with below code.

```
 foreach ($array1 as $value) {    
      if(!empty($value)) {
            echo "Not empty";
      } else {
            echo "EMPTY";
      }
 }
```

Note : `isset()` function not check the empty value. It's only check variable is set or not.

Comment: `isset && !empty` is superfluous. Just use `!empty`. In fact, just use `!$value`, which will do just fine.

Comment: @deceze, Yes it's good but `isset()` not affected.